# Servicestack - Call AuthProvider automatically

Tags: servicestack

I would like to build my own AuthProvider. It should

1. Check if ss-id cookie is set and check for a valid session (this is
   done automatically in servicestack)
2. If no valid session was found check a custom http-header (e.g. X-Api-Token)
3. If found a valid token create a new session
4. If not found a valid token send 401 Unauthorized

Basically this is the behaviour of the CredentialsAuthProvider except that I need to check for the X-Api-Token without making an explicit call to /auth/credentials. However the AuthProvider is never called automatically.

Any ideas how to get this done?

Edit: One idea was to use a request filter but there is still something missing:

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((request, response, arg3) =>
   {
      //If there is a valid ss-id cookie the it should have precedence and the request should be authenticated accordingly
      if (!ValidatedViaSsIdCookie())
      {
         if (HeaderHasCorrectApiKey()) {
            //Authenticate the current request by creating a new Session
            AuthenticateRequest();
         }
      }
   }
);
```

How to implement ValidatedViaSsIdCookie() and AuthenticateRequest()???

Edit: I don't think GlobalRequestFilters are the way to go because they will be executed after authentication... So if there is no valid session the filter is not executed at all and my Api key is never checked... Still searching for a better solution...

Regards

Dirk

Comment: I've done something similar with a simple request filter attribute. If you go that route, set the `Priority` of that filter equal to `RequestFilterPriority.Authenticate`.

Comment: I tried to do that with a GlobalRequestFilter. But could not find out how to Check if there is already a valid ss-id cookie (which should have precedence) and how to Authorize a request. I've edited my question to demonstrate...